# How can I change the text color of all gui elements like labels or buttons or just text to white color?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is example of what white color and text/font size and style I want to get in my project taken from another project.

[image: Example]

I want to get in the editorwindow background color and the white text color like in the screenshot.

I don't need a treeview just to make this kind of text.
I'm using EditorWindow type script.

In the top I did:

```
private static Texture2D tex;
```

Then:

```
    [MenuItem("Window/Test")]
        static void ShowEditor()
        {
            editor = EditorWindow.GetWindow<Test>();
            editor.Init();

            tex = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
            tex.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.black);
            tex.Apply();

            CenterWindow();
        }

And inside the OnGUI:

void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, maxSize.x, maxSize.y), tex, ScaleMode.StretchToFill);
        //GUI.Label(new Rect(200, 200, 100, 100), "A label");
        //GUI.TextField(new Rect(20, 20, 70, 30), "");

        GUIStyle itemStyle = new GUIStyle();  //make a new GUIStyle

        itemStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleLeft; //align text to the left
        itemStyle.active.background = itemStyle.normal.background;  //gets rid of button click background style.
        itemStyle.margin = new RectOffset(0, 0, 0, 0);
        GUI.backgroundColor = Color.white;
        GUI.skin.toggle.fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal;
        GUI.skin.toggle.fontSize = 13;
    }
```

But it didn't change much. It draw and colored the whole window in black but the elements the gui elements are not in white like in the screenshot example.

Comment: I think that `itemStyle.normal.textColor = Color.white;` should do the trick.

Comment: @mayo Still not working. The text and fonts of all elements like labels buttons all in black color.

Comment: I tried this and is working; Are you setting up the style before using it?
`private void OnGUI()
    {
        var rect = new Rect(10, 10, Screen.width, Screen.height);
        var labelText = "Example";

        var style = new GUIStyle();
        style.normal.textColor = Color.red;

        GUI.Label(rect, labelText, style);
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `itemStyle.normal.textColor = Color.white;`. Adding this should make all the text with this style turn white